# Typeorm Migration for self referencing migration

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, typeorm

Im trying to create migration for self referencing model like described here in TypeOrm docs

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations-faq.md#how-to-create-self-referencing-relation

But how can I create a migration for these self-referencing relations here:

I got model:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne, OneToMany} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Category {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    text: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Category, category => category.childCategories)
    parentCategory: Category;

    @OneToMany(type => Category, category => category.parentCategory)
    childCategories: Category[];

}
```

And my migration looks like this:

```
export class createCategoryTable1576071180569 implements MigrationInterface {
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(
            new Table({
                name: 'category',
                columns: [
                    { name: 'id', type: 'int', isPrimary: true, isGenerated: true, generationStrategy: 'increment' },
                    { name: 'text', type: 'varchar' },
                    { name: 'parentId', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'childId', type: 'int' },
                ],
            }),
            true,
        );

        await queryRunner.createForeignKey(
            'category',
            new TableForeignKey({
                columnNames: ['parentId'],
                referencedColumnNames: ['id'],
                referencedTableName: 'category',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            }),
        );
}
```

I think it is ok, but how do I create a foreign key in migration for Child categories since it is supposed to be an array of categories ???

Comment: found out the issue was the column name 
use 'parent_id' insread of 'parentId'. Typeorm is probably case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Man, i got the same error , i dont know if its gonna help you, but in your column

```
 { name: 'parentId', type: 'int' },
```

change for this

```
   { name: 'parentId', type: 'int' , unsigned: true},
```